# ng-repeat with JSON in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON

```
{"uuid":"5634","day":"three","one":{},"two":{},"three":{"people":[{"name":"sam","count":"2"},{"name":"das","count":"5"},{"name":"smith","count":"12"},]}}
```

I want to repeat only the data from the key "three". Is it possible to map that with the value "day"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Controller, derive a new `$scope` variable for the data you wish to use in your view:

```
var data = {"uuid":"5634","day":"three","one":{},"two":{},"three":{"people":[{"name":"sam","count":"2"},{"name":"das","count":"5"},{"name":"smith","count":"12"},]}};
$scope.dayData = data[data.day];
```

Then use that variable in your view by amending the `ng-repeat` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in dayData.people">
  <h1>{{ person.name }}</h1>
  <p>Count : {{ person.count }}</p>
</div>
```

[**Example Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ym5cdpOb7CEgNAOzkcbf?p=preview)